# Не изменять размер блока при масштабировании окна

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет!

Возник вопрос.. При изменении масштаба в браузере, как отменить масштабирование для одного блока?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если выставлять размеры в единицах измерения vw, которые высчитываются относительно экрана, то блок будет всегда визуально одинакового размера. 1vw = 1% от экрана (не от контейнера!)

```
.block {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  background: red;
}
```

Это же работает на любой другой контент: границы, размер шрифта, закругления...

Comment: спасибо! что-то подобное да, буду подгонять))

Answer (score 0):

Задать фиксированную ширину, высоту

Comment: Так и сделано, но при изменении масштаба страница (а именно CTRL + +, CTRL + -) всеравно уменьшается..